# Can I tell the JPanel paintComponent(Graphics g) function to only repaint the object I'm editing?

Tags: java, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm writing an app in java using a `JPanel` to draw maps, I've used `Landmass` as a class, and the workspace (extends JPanel) uses multiple landmasses to represent each continent/island.

currently, the paintComponent runs a for loop over every Landmass every time I `repaint()`, which is everytime the mouse is moved. This seems inefficient as most Landmasses aren't changing, and is causing my program to slow down when too many Landmass objects are added. I want the landmasses to still be displayed by the graphics, I'm looking for a way to not redraw the ones I haven't edited.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;
            zoom(g2);
            
   int radius = zoomHandler.divZ(this.radius);
   graphicsHandler.setRadius(radius);

            ...
            
   if(!landmasses.isEmpty()) 
    for(int i = 0; i < landmasses.size(); i++)
         graphicsHandler.drawLandmass(g2, landmasses.get(i), i);
}
```

Where landmasses is the `ArrayList<Landmass>` that I'm using to store every Landmass.

To be clear, I never directly call the paintComponent, I only ever use repaint();

If anyone was wondering drawLandmas does:

```
public void drawLandmass(Graphics2D g, Landmass l, int index) {
        int[] xPoints = new int[l.nodes.size()]; //setup two integer arrays to store the x and y coordinates of each point
        int[] yPoints = new int[l.nodes.size()];
        for(int j = 0; j < l.nodes.size(); j++)//and assign each of the arrays with the points we take from the nodes
        {
            xPoints[j] = l.nodes.get(j).x();
            yPoints[j] = l.nodes.get(j).y();
        }
        fillLandmass(l, xPoints, yPoints,g);
        if(l.getIsSelected()) {
            traceLandmass(l, xPoints, yPoints, g);
            boxLandmass(l, w.zoomHandler, g);
        }
    }
    
    public void fillLandmass(Landmass l, int[] x, int[] y, Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(l.getColor());
        g.fillPolygon(x, y, l.nodes.size());
    
        
    }
    
    public void traceLandmass(Landmass l, int[] x, int[] y, Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawPolygon(x,y,l.nodes.size());
        for(int j = 0; j < l.nodes.size(); j++)//and assign each of the arrays with the points we take from the nodes
        {
            if(l.getSelectedNode() == j)
                circle(g, l.nodes.get(j), "fill", radius,g.getColor());
            else
                circle(g, l.nodes.get(j), "draw", radius,g.getColor());
        }
    }
    
    public void boxLandmass(Landmass l, ZoomHandler z, Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawRect(l.prox[0] - radius, l.prox[1] - radius,
                l.prox[2]-l.prox[0] + 2*radius, 
                l.prox[3]-l.prox[1] + 2*radius);
        g.fillRect(l.prox[0] - z.divZ(3) - radius, l.prox[1] - z.divZ(3) - radius, 2*z.divZ(3), 2*z.divZ(3));
        g.fillRect(l.prox[2] - z.divZ(3) + radius, l.prox[1] - z.divZ(3) - radius, 2*z.divZ(3), 2*z.divZ(3));
        g.fillRect(l.prox[2] - z.divZ(3) + radius, l.prox[3] - z.divZ(3) + radius, 2*z.divZ(3), 2*z.divZ(3));
        g.fillRect(l.prox[0] - z.divZ(3) - radius, l.prox[3] - z.divZ(3) + radius, 2*z.divZ(3), 2*z.divZ(3));
    
        if(l.centreNodeVisible)
            circle(g,l.centreNode,"draw",radius, g.getColor());
    }
```

I obviously can't just use an `if(landmasses.get(i).isEdited())` statement to only draw landmasses which have been edited, and the unedited ones won't be shown.

I tried researching the paintComponent, but I couldn't find anything there that was helpful.

Comment: Generally, you have to repaint everything. Only repainting a part of the component is trickier but possible.

Comment: How would I do that? Is it possible to repaint a specific object while keeping everything else as is?

Comment: Not sure why moving the mouse causes a repaint. Maybe each landmass could be a BufferedImage. Then the paintComponent() methods simply paints each image. Or maybe you only have a single BufferedImage that you recreate whenever a landmass is edited.

Comment: I need to adjust the shape of landmasses using the mouse, meaning that I need to repaint when I do that. It's not so much a problem with moving the mouse, but it is with dragging the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the technical details [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html), the `Graphics` object has a "clip rectangle" property, which indicates which area should be redrawn:

> - The `Graphics` object's *clip rectangle* is set to the area of the component that is in need of repainting.

It is used/set when you call the [`repaint()` method with the integer arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint-int-int-int-int-) to specify the region you need to repaint. So when you call

```
panel.repaint(10, 20, 30, 40); // rectangle of 30x40 at pos (10, 20)
```

the `paint*()` methods get called with a `Graphics` object, where `getClip()` will return a [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)/[`Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) with these coordinates (or the coordinates related to *that* GUI component). You can use this information to (re)draw only the parts in that area. But this also means that you have to call `repaint()` on the area that has been changed. If you call `repaint()` without arguments, you will give the Swing/AWT drawing library no information whatsoever what has been "changed" and what is "unchanged", resulting in repainting *everything* (because that's what you are requesting).

See the following prototype to show the effect of `repaint(...);` and how the `paintComponent()` method is called:

```
public class Testing extends JPanel {
    
    private int paintCounter = 0;
    
    private Color[] colors = new Color[] {
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.RED,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.YELLOW,
            Color.ORANGE,
            Color.PINK
    };
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(colors[paintCounter++%colors.length]);
        Rectangle r = (Rectangle)g.getClip();
        System.out.println(r);
        if (r.getX() == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        g.fillRect((int)r.getX(), (int)r.getY(), (int)r.getWidth(), (int)r.getHeight());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        Testing panel = new Testing();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);         
        });
        
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("Going to repaint step "+i);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    int x = r.nextInt(100)+10;
                    int y = r.nextInt(100)+100;
                    int width = r.nextInt(100)+100;
                    int height = r.nextInt(100)+100;
                    System.out.println("Repaint at: x="+x+", y="+y+", width="+width+", height="+height);
                    frame.repaint(x, y, width, height);
                });
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }    
}
```

This will create a window like this:

[image: JFrame screenshot]

The debug output looks as follow:

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=390,height=470]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1,height=1]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=390,height=470]
Going to repaint step 0
Repaint at: x=60, y=150, width=108, height=191
java.awt.Rectangle[x=56,y=117,width=108,height=191]
Going to repaint step 1
Repaint at: x=58, y=161, width=171, height=112
java.awt.Rectangle[x=54,y=128,width=171,height=112]
Going to repaint step 2
Repaint at: x=91, y=195, width=108, height=153
java.awt.Rectangle[x=87,y=162,width=108,height=153]
Going to repaint step 3
Repaint at: x=96, y=186, width=109, height=117
java.awt.Rectangle[x=92,y=153,width=109,height=117]
Going to repaint step 4
Repaint at: x=81, y=194, width=170, height=128
java.awt.Rectangle[x=77,y=161,width=170,height=128]
Going to repaint step 5
Repaint at: x=11, y=168, width=114, height=101
java.awt.Rectangle[x=7,y=135,width=114,height=101]
Going to repaint step 6
Repaint at: x=96, y=151, width=137, height=199
java.awt.Rectangle[x=92,y=118,width=137,height=199]
Going to repaint step 7
Repaint at: x=99, y=167, width=127, height=130
java.awt.Rectangle[x=95,y=134,width=127,height=130]
Going to repaint step 8
Repaint at: x=23, y=107, width=167, height=118
java.awt.Rectangle[x=19,y=74,width=167,height=118]
Going to repaint step 9
Repaint at: x=42, y=155, width=167, height=103
java.awt.Rectangle[x=38,y=122,width=167,height=103]
```

As you see in the output, the `paintComponent()` method is called with a rectangle of the whole `JPanel` size first, since in the beginning it has to been drawn fully at least once. After that only the specific part should be drawn and the `paintComponent()` method does that.

However, keep in mind that the drawing system of Swing/AWT will decide really quick that is must redraw everything. GUI actions like focus switch or resize can result in the Swing/AWT system thinking "Well, what I am currently showing is not current anymore, I have to redraw everything" and calls `repaint()` without any limits.